# Is there a way in Azure to create VMs from templates as easily as in Google Cloud?

Tags: azure

In Google Cloud Platform I can just create a template right from the console setting a few options (eg. CPU size, GPU size, startup script etc) and then I can just create a VM any time from that template, and change any parameters before deploying it. This is super useful. No code, no need to leave the console.

In contrast, in Microsoft's Azure, the whole template manipulation is very cumbersome, although they too claim it is supposed to serve the purpose of 'easily' re-create resources with certain configurations. I may just not be aware of a better way to do it, but when I save a configuration as a template, already there is this json template file it creates and as I understand I am supposed to somehow find the configured properties in it, but really I don't see any of the properties defined in it. In gcloud for example, saving a template with a certain startup script added was part of the options, but in Azure even the startup script I add to cloud_init field, I have no idea where to locate it in the downloaded template that was generated from it. Then I thought maybe I can just try and import that template during VM creation and then change the parameters I need to, but the only option I get in the console for saved templates is to 'deploy' directly. Even deploying it requires to fill about 15 fields before it actually gets deployed and then click 'purchase this template' (the one I created myself) so then I am already better off going through the VM creation dialogue and retyping the configuration manually because even that is faster then deploying a template from the console.

As I see the proposed pipeline in Azure is something like, if you want to re-create a configuration with just a few changes, download the template for an existing configuration, use code editor to replace certain fields in the json (after figuring out where are your embedded properties, but the naming of the properties is different from the naming in the console so this is far from a quick task), then use the Azure CLI command line tool to deploy the template (because apparently there is no quick way to deploy it in the portal)

Is this really how it is supposed to work or is there some way to save and re-use configurations while also change certain properties - using the Azure portal only?

Answer (score 0):

The tool that can help is Visual Studio 2019, downloadable with the
[Azure DevOps Server 2019 virtual machine](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/devopsvmdownload/)
(30 GB) that is provided by Microsoft.

Using Visual Studio, you will have JSON outline, auto-completion, on-line help
and more.

[image]

To start, see the Microsoft Azure DevOps Lab article
[Authoring ARM Templates with Visual Studio](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/armtemplates/).

Comment: Thank you, this certainly helps although it is not as quick and clean as the VM-from-template portal-only GUI solution that I am used to with Gcloud. And 30GB local disk space is too much for a tool that I would probably only use for template automation - because other than this issue, I've been ok using the in-portal UI without the need for the Azure VM